How to Set Values to NaN for Specific Time Period in PySpark DataFrame?
I have a Spark DataFrame containing monthly data from January 2018 to December 2026. The DataFrame has the following columns:
dt: A string representing the year and month (e.g., "2018-01").
avg_price: A numerical value for the price.
avg_rev_price: A numerical value for the revenue price.(growth rate),
output:
I wanna fill my future NA value by using previous year's value * (1+avg_rev_price)
For example:
for Jan/24 my avg price is 100, and Jan/25 and Jan/26 is NULL but I have avg_rev_for both and it is 10% for both Jan/25 and Jan/26
Calc: avg_price for Jan'25 = avg_price for Jan'24 * (1+avg_rev_price)
                           = 100 *(1+10%)
                           = 110
    Similarly, avg_price for Jan'26 = avg_price for Jan'25 * (1+avg_rev_price)
                                    = 110*(1+10%)
                                    = 121

so new updated values in avg price would be 110,121 for jan/25 and jan/256 respectively.
my code:
windowSpec=Window.orderBy("dt").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)
df = df.withColumn("avg_price", expr("avg_price").cast("double"))\
       .withColumn("avg_price", coalesce(col("avg_price"), lag(col("avg_price") * (1 + col("avg_rev_price")), 1).over(windowSpec)))

